# How to upgrade ColdFusion version from 10 to 2016?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-2016, cfadmin

One of my application is running on ColdFusion 10 and that will become unsupported in May 2019. So Client wants me to Upgrade to a higher version, may be 11 0r 2016. Can someone please help me with the procedure? I mean whom should I contact? How should I upgrade? What precautions should I take? What is the cost involved?

Comment: ColdFusion 11 support will end shortly: https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2019/02/coldfusion-11-core-support-ends-april-2019/ You best upgrade to CF 2016 or CF 2018.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler: Sure. Can you also let me know the procedure for it? Whom should I contact for the upgrade(I have emailed to this already - 'cf.install@adobe.com') ? Is there any cost involved in it? Do I need to un-install CF10 from system and then install CF2016 again or entering the serial key would just suffice(auto conversion)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can someone please help me with the procedure?** **I mean whom should I contact?**

You can contact Adobe sales coldfusionsales@adobe.com and/or support directly by emailing cfinstal@adobe.com (notice that it is only one 'l' and no period). They can help you with purchasing a license and getting support for what you need.

You can also request information online - [Request for contact](https://www.adobe.com/products/request-consultation/coldfusion.html)

**How should I upgrade?** **What precautions should I take?**

They can help you answer this question too. Basically you can either upgrade the existing server in place or build out a new server and switch over to that server when you are ready. I prefer the second method as it leaves the current server in place while you work through creating the new environment.

There is also documentation online to help guide you. [ColdFusion User Guide - INSTALL COLDFUSION](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/user-guide.html?topic=/coldfusion/morehelp/installing-coldfusion.ug.js)

**What is the cost involved?**

Depends on the kind of license you need. See the [ColdFusion buying guide](https://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-family/buying-guide.html) for more info. You have the option to purchase directly from Adobe or from a third-party reseller. Contact info is on that page I referenced.

As far as specific costs, from the [Adobe FAQ site here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/standard/faq.html):

> Adobe ColdFusion (2018 release) is sold in two editions: Standard Edition costs US$2,499 per two CPUs, and Enterprise Edition costs US$9,499 per two CPUs. ColdFusion can also be used for development at no cost with the complimentary Developer Edition, a full-featured server for development use only.

---

**Or you can go the free, open source, route and install Lucee instead**

> Light-weight dynamic CFML scripting language with a solid foundation
>   Lucee is the leading open-source CFML application server/engine. Lucee provides a lot of functionality (tags and functions) to deal with all kinds of web related actions. Manipulating images, PDF files, XML, string, numbers, dates and a lot more. You name it, Lucee does it for you! Lucee has built-in support not only to call existing web services, it can also generate web services for you in the most simple way.

[Lucee Documentation](https://docs.lucee.org/)

[Installing Lucee](https://docs.lucee.org/guides/installing-lucee.html)

Comment: Thanks!! I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Vasu I would also note that there are significant language improvements from 10 to 2016/2018. Not to mention there is probably some code in the CF10 version that will need to make use of some of those improvements, especially in the security realm. So in addition to the server upgrade and the testing of the codebase, I would also budget in some refactoring time to make and test those improvements.